# WPF DataGridComboBoxColumn TextBinding not updating

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, material-design-in-xaml

I am attempting to use a DataGridComboBoxColumn but I'm having trouble with displaying the text associated with the Selected Item. Technically, I'm using MaterialDataGridComboBoxColumn which extends DataGridComboBoxColumn (see that code  [here.](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/master/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf/MaterialDataGridComboBoxColumn.cs) The only real difference seems to be the addition of ItemSourceBinding which makes binding to a non static list easier.)

Here is the ComboBox in xaml:

```
<materialDesign:MaterialDataGridComboBoxColumn 
    Header="Meter" 
    ElementStyle="{StaticResource CenterEverything}" 
    ItemsSourceBinding="{Binding PotentialMeters}"
    DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
    TextBinding="{Binding Segment.Meter.Name, Mode=OneWay}" 
    SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Segment.Meter, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

The item source for the DataGrid is made of an ObservableCollection consisting of SegmentWrappers:

```
public sealed class SegmentWrapper : INotifyPropertyChanged {
        public Segment Segment { get; set; }

        public List<Meter> PotentialMeters => GetPotentialMeters();

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private List<Meter> GetPotentialMeters() => Segment.Station.AllMeters;

    }
```

The Segment object is my actual model:

```
public sealed class Segment :  INotifyPropertyChanged {

        public Station Station { get; set; }

        public Meter Meter { get; set; }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Now, the weird thing is I can get this to work sometimes when I'm running in debug. Normally, when I start up I cannot not see the name of the selected Meter in the ComboBox, but if I remove and re-add the TextBinding attribute from the xaml above while the code is running, the name is displayed correctly! I guess this has something to do with the UpdateSourceTrigger, but I cannot figure it out. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a workaround for this now (so perhaps this should not be considered an answer? I'm new to SO, so I will happily post this as a comment if it should not be an answer).

I switched over to a DataGridTemplateColumn and basically used the same binding for everything and it worked. I changed my original xaml to this:

```
 <DataGridTemplateColumn  Header="Meter" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ComboBox   Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignDataGridComboBox}" 
                            Foreground="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignBody}"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding PotentialMeters, Mode=OneWay}" 
                            DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                            Text="{Binding Segment.Meter.Name, Mode=OneWay}" 
                            SelectedItem="{Binding Segment.Meter}">
                </ComboBox>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

I have no real answer as to why the original approach didn't work, but I'm happy with this.

Answer (score 0):

In the setter of your segment propeties, notify the property to reflect in the UI

Comment: `PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Meter")`

You mean something like this in the setter? It did not improve my situation, but thanks!

Comment: You may need to make the list of meters an observable collection instead of a list. Anything that is bound to XAML needs to be observable.

Comment: The list of meters displays correctly though, so I do not believe this is an issue. It is only the selected item that does not display correctly.